# How to check which bootstrap modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which is checking to see if a modal is open on the page.
If a bootstrap is open i need to be able to get the name of it.

```
        $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {

            var tf = $('div.modal').hasClass('in');

            if (tf == true)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                $('#search').click();
            }

        }
    });
```

If you could provide with code that generates the ID of the currently open modal that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: using `$('div.modal.in').attr('id')`?

Comment: thats great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var activeModal_id = $('div.modal.in').attr('id');`
[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

Comment: great answer, works perfectly. Would you know how i would then go about getting the ID of a submit button inside activeModal_id?

Comment: Yes, using `$('div.modal.in button[type="submit"]').attr('id')` or `$(activeModal_id).find('button[type="submit"]').attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Assign each modal with a unique id, and then find the id of the open-modal, 
and check **in** class their to identify modal is open or not.

```
$('div.modal.in').attr('id')
```